# Android Actionbar with Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am very new to Android and Java programming. What I am trying to do is to get Actionbar with couple of tabs (11 in final). I have managed to install ActionBar Sherlock but then I am stuck with adding tabs to actionbar. From what I read it looks that also I would need to add separate Fragment for each tab. Is there a simple solution how to make that work.

Comment: What are you stuck with specifically? Your question isn't detailed enough for anyone to provide an answer to it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have added more datails on my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a fragment per tab in the action bar. It should just be as simple as defining your menu in xml, then in your activity initialising the action bar with your menu.

For instance your menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/my_menu_item"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText"
          android:title="Tab name here"/>
</menu>
```

Then in your activity override onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then you'll need to override onOptionItemSelected to respond to when a tab is pressed:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.my_menu_item:
                    //do something
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. Although I have one more question. Is is possible to make all items in menu scrollable.

Comment: Depends on how you want it to be displayed. There's a framework called ViewPagerIndicator that does "scrollable tabs" developed by the same guy who made ActionBarSherlock. Take a look at http://viewpagerindicator.com/ and see if it meets your needs.